# How to disable dragAndDrop failed animation?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

In javascript, when an element is dragged outside of invalid drop area.

How to disable the failed drop animation? (shadow of dragged element is moving back to the dragged element position)

see screenshot:
[image]

code from mozila example:

```
const source = document.getElementById("source");
const target = document.getElementById("target");
const event_log = document.getElementById("event-log");

function dragstart_handler(ev) {
  event_log.textContent += "dragStart\n";
  // Change the source element's background color to signify drag has started
  ev.currentTarget.style.border = "dashed";
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function dragover_handler(ev) {
  event_log.textContent += "dragOver\n";
  // Change the target element's border to signify a drag over event
  // has occurred
  ev.currentTarget.style.background = "lightblue";
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drop_handler(ev) {
  event_log.textContent += "Drop\n";
  ev.preventDefault();
  const data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}

function dragenter_handler(ev) {
  event_log.textContent += "dragEnter\n";
  // Change the source element's background color for enter events
  ev.currentTarget.style.background = "yellow";
}

function dragleave_handler(ev) {
  event_log.textContent += "dragLeave\n";
  // Change the source element's border back to white
  ev.currentTarget.style.background = "white";
}

function dragend_handler(ev) {
  event_log.textContent += "dragEnd\n";
  // Change the target element's background color to visually indicate
  // the drag ended.
  target.style.background = "pink";
}

// Set handlers for the source's drag - start/enter/leave/end events
source.ondragstart = dragstart_handler;
source.ondragenter = dragenter_handler;
source.ondragleave = dragleave_handler;
source.ondragend = dragend_handler;

// Set handlers for the target's drop and dragover events
target.ondrop = drop_handler;
target.ondragover = dragover_handler;

// Set click event listener on button to reload the example
const button = document.getElementById("reload");
button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.location.reload();
});

full example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/ondragend
```

Comment: Have you tried `event.preventDefault()` on the `dragend` handler?

Comment: @Noam doesn't seems to work.
https://jsfiddle.net/bekicot/4q9reo2c/

Comment: I just tried on both Chrome and Firefox for windows and there don't seem to be such an animation regardless of the JS. What is your OS and browser? If it's an OS or browser effect it is totally possible that JS cannot change it. As a side note, it seems that Firefox identifies all `<textarea>`s as valid drop areas - I guess the Drag and Drop specifications may be vague and leave details to implementation.